# npm ERR! Tracker "idealTree:inflate:" already exists

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

Every time I try to install packages using `npm install`, I'm getting `npm ERR! Tracker "idealTree:inflate:" already exists` error.

I've tried removing `node_modules` and clearing cache, but no luck for me.

Comment: Can you share your package.json and confirm you're running `npm install` in the project root? Have you tried deleting your lock file?

Comment: @JBallin https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/trunk/package.json
yes, I'm trying on project root

Comment: Did you confirm that your node + npm versions fall within the range specified in the package.json?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when trying to update a v1 lockfile to v2 with npmv7, as it seems to be the case in your codebase, and the only way to make it work was to delete the lockfile, clear the cache and do a `npm i` again with the --prefer-dedupe flag.
With the package-lock rebuilt, `npm i` with no flag worked again, as did `npm ci`.

Before that, I tried `npm i --legacy-peer-deps` as it seemed to mimic npm v6 not installing peer dependencies and it failed too, however I think it's interesting to know this flag exists, check out the npm 7 announcement page for more clues : https://github.blog/2021-02-02-npm-7-is-now-generally-available/#peer-dependencies

TLDR

```
rm package-lock.json
npm cache clear --force
npm i --prefer-dedupe
```

Comment: Deleting the package-lock.json is a pretty significant "fix", especially in an environment where you are relying on the lock file for reproducible builds.

Comment: You're right but OP implied it was on its own computer, not on the CI machines. When using npm for the CI, it's best to use npm ci with a correct lockfile, indeed.

Answer (score 1):

`npm update && npm i` works for me.

Source: https://github.com/npm/arborist/issues/330#issuecomment-947803995

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was:

- Remove *package-lock.json* and *node_modules* **on the project root**.
- `npm cache clear --force`
- `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`

Note: I need to install the dependencies with the flag because of the nature of the project, but it should work just by normally reinstalling the deps with `npm install`.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs in node v14, I upgrade to node v16.17.0 fix it

Answer (score 0):

This might help others:

In my case I had a very small web app. Just a 'app.js' and a 'readme.md'. No 'package.json'. When deploying (using Azure Deployment Center) it returned with error 'Tracker "idealTree:inflate:" already exists'.

When I committed a 'package.json' file the deployment succeeded.